# CakePHP find contain having deep orders

Tags: sql, cakephp, relationship

I have the following models:

```
Client hasMany Loan
Loan belongsTo Book
Loan belongsTo Client
Book belongsTo BookType
```

And my tables look like this:

```
clients { id, name, ... }
loans { id, client_id, book_id }
books { id, book_type_id }
book_types { id, title }
```

I would like to find all loans by a Clients's id. This is what I tried:

```
$client = $this->Client->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Client.id' => $id
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'Loan' => array(
            'Book' => array(
                'BookType' => array(
                    'order' => 'sachtitel DESC'
                )
            )
        )
    )
));
```

This doesn't work as expected. My data isn't sorted as I wanted it to be.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Okay, it seems, as long as I am using *contain*, I can't use the order, because CakePHP generates multiple queries to obtain the data. Thus my order is useless, because only 1 row is fetched by the queries generated by CakePHP.
How would I use join, to fetch data from the table?

Comment: "My data isn't sorted as I wanted it to be." - please clarify - what do you want, and how does that differ from what you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Define the order while creating the relationships. Try something like this:

```
$this->Book->bindModel(array(
    'belongsTo' => array(
       'BookType' => array('order' => 'sachtitel DESC' )
));
```